# Can a table field contain a hyphen?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in a MySQL table with a fieldname 'product', and want to rename it to 'ds-product'.

The CMS type system I am using uses the id of formfields as the name of the table field to insert into.

For most this works fine, but for a particular field it prepends 'ds-' to whatever ID I give it, so I must make the table field name match.

However, when trying to do a query I get the error that

Unknown column 'sales.ds' in 'field list'

Is there any way I can have a field called ds-product?

Comment: It is possible, but you don't want to do this because you'll have to enclose that table name in the proper quoting character for your database *every single time*.  Have you considered using an underscore instead?

Comment: @Charles: your comment should have been an answer

Comment: @Charles: +1, non-standard column names should be a last resort for the reason you just stated.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, you can use punctuation, white space, international characters, and SQL reserved words if you use *delimited identifiers*:

```
SELECT * FROM `my-table`;
```

In MySQL, use the back-ticks.  In standard SQL, use double-quotes.

Or if you use MySQL you can set the [`ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes):

```
SET SQL_MODE = ANSI_QUOTES;
SELECT * FROM "my-table";
```

Comment: I don´t actually have access to the query which gets used. Is there any way to have a field called ds-product and have it used in a standard query?

Comment: No, the hyphen is an operator, and you can't use that in the middle of an identifier.  What if you also had columns `ds` and `product`?  Then `ds-product` would be an arithmetic expression: one column minus the other column.  SQL supports delimited identifiers so you can resolve this ambiguity.  FWIW, I don't know any other programming language that would allow this at all!

Answer (score 7):

Try putting brackets on the last part of your call on the table. in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE-NAME];
```

just make sure to put the brackets on the table name only. not on the whole database it is located

```
SELECT * FROM some_database.anotherdatabase.[your-table];
```

P.S. works on columns, too.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management.

Comment: Alas, MS SQL and MySQL are different, and often require different answers.  You can't mix them.  I'd recommend deleting this answer before you get a bunch of downvotes.

Comment: The answer is correct for users of Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft Access, or Sybase. It might help other readers who use those brands of database.