# Adding backticks to a variable in perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I have MYSQL database that has field names containing hyphens. Trying to insert data from XML to database using Perl.I have XML in %HEAD
The keys are the column header and values are the corresponding data.

```
my %HEAD= ('REGISTRATION-NUMBER' => 'AAACT2727QXM003',
           'RETURN-YEAR' => '2013', 
           'MONTH' => 'July', 
           'LTU' => 'Yes',
           'NIL-RETURN' => 'No',
           'ASSESSEE-NAME' => 'TATA MOTORS LIMITED');

my @HEADER_keys= keys %HEAD;


foreach $key(@HEADER_keys) {    
    $value= $HEAD{$key};
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO indirect_taxes($key) VALUES ($value)");
    $sth->execute() or die $sth->errstr;
}
```

or instead of foreach

```
my @HEADER_values= values %HEAD;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO indirect_taxes(?) VALUES (?)");

$sth->execute_array(\@HEADER_keys, \@HEADER_values) or die "the failure cause: $DBI::errstr";
```

As the keys are containing hyphens i am getting MYSQL syntax error. From [Can a table field contain a hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168644/can-a-table-field-contain-a-hyphen)

got the syntax but using perl not able to add backtick to the variable $key or @HEADER_keys.

Please suggest a way to add backticks to $keys.

Comment: I know nothing about Perl but I think you should edit your question and explain what exactly prevents you from adding the backticks. Do you need to keep the unquoted name for some other usage?

Comment: You should use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) instead of interpolating variables.

Comment: @ Alvaro In perl backticks execute a command and perl script is continued after the command has finished.

Comment: @mudBorn - Even inside a string? Well, it's obvious what I said: I know nothing about Perl xD

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try back sticks around `$key` and use sql placeholder `?` to avoid [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
foreach my $key(keys %HEAD) {
  my $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO indirect_taxes (%s) VALUES (?)",
      $dbh->quote_identifier($key));
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute($HEAD{$key})
      or die $sth->errstr;
}
```

Comment: Why just one placeholder?

Comment: @TLP placeholder for values, you want to use it for key also?

Comment: AFAIK you can prepare statements only with values placeholders

Comment: Might depend on the driver.

Comment: @choroba it might be. btw, how can you check if statement is prepared with execution plan, or driver only simulates preparation?

Comment: Your solution still suffered from SQL injection --Imagine a backtick in `$key`-- so I fixed it by using `$dbh->quote_identifier`.