# Mysql Insert prepared statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having problem to insert some staff in a 3th table.

Table first contains **first_id, test_name**
| Table second contains **second_id, test_second**
| Table first-second contains **first_id, second_id, note** (can be null)

```
$first_id = 1;
$second_id = 3;

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO first-second (first_id, second_id) values (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $first_id, $second_id);
$result_insert = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

In PHPMyadmin I can do the insert but I don't know why with stmt doesn'work.

Thank you.

Comment: Try removing `$result_insert = ` since you're not calling that variable after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid to define table name with dash, it's not a good practice. Anyway you can solve your problem just putting backticks between the name of the table.

Something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO `table-mame` WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add backticks around your table name:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `first-second` (first_id, second_id) values (?, ?)");
```

It is advised though, to not use "strange" characters in table names.

Comment: I had a feeling about the hyphen myself, I just wasn't 100% sure. I never use hyphens myself; anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using textbox/textarea or any other type that ask for input to insert data into your database. Your input might have special characters in it that cause for the query to fail. Try using `mysqli_real_escape_string` before your insert query.

```
$input1=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['input1']);
$input2=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['input2']);
$input3=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['input3']);

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO first-second (first_id, second_id, note) VALUES ('$input1','$input2','$input3')");
```

By the way, it's okay to use hyphen in a table name, but not recommendable:

[Can a table field contain a hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168644/can-a-table-field-contain-a-hyphen)

Answer (score 0):

```
$first_id = 1;
$second_id = 3;

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO first-second (first_id, second_id) values (:f1, :f2)");
$result_insert = $stmt->execute(array('f1'=>$first_id , 'f2'=>$second_id));
$stmt->close();
```

Hope this help.

Thanks