# How to reference SQL Server table via SAS libname with hyphen in name

Tags: sas

I am attempting to use Proc Sql to query a table in a SQL server database called *Code_07-12_dim*. SAS interprets a hyphen as some other meaning, and the following code returns an error:

```
proc sql;
SELECT * FROM lib1.Code_07-12_dim;
quit;
```

Log output:

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, ;, (, ',', ANSIMISS, AS, CROSS, EXCEPT, FULL, GROUP, HAVING, INNER, INTERSECT, JOIN, LEFT, NATURAL, NOMISS, ORDER, OUTER, RIGHT, UNION, WHERE.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored
```

How can I reference this table? Note that the SQL server is managed by another department, and while I intend to chide them for using hyphens in their table names, I am unable to change the name of the table.

Comment: I think this answers your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168644/can-a-table-field-contain-a-hyphen

Comment: @double_j This is a SAS-specific question. Simply wrapping the table name in quotes does not work here. I changed the question title to be more specific.

Comment: @Patrick It's incorrect to include "SAS" like you did in the title; that's what tags are for (the fact that several people seem to be unable to read them notwithstanding).  I edited in a compromise title that's allowed (SAS is okay in the middle, just not at the start like that).

Comment: I'm surprised it let you do it, tbh; in a new question that title would be rejected (or is supposed to be!)

Comment: Not sure who keeps voting to close - this is clearly not a duplicate of the reference question, which deals specifically with MySQL, not SAS.

Comment: Unfortunately it's in the CV queue and will be looked at by people who don't know much about any of this, so it may end up being closed; if so, then we should be able to get it reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
proc sql;
 SELECT * FROM lib1.'Code_07-12_dim'n;
quit;
```

That's called a "name literal" and is SAS's version of the square brackets commonly used elsewhere.

It's possible you also need the option `options validmemname=any;`.