# How i can remove this error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.

And this is the code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ucp_beschwerde (date, tat_name, opfer_name, vergehen, content, one-url, two-url, three-url) VALUES (:date, :tat_name, :opfer_name, :vergehen, :content, :one-url, :two-url, :three-url)";
$smt = $db->prepare($query);
$smt->execute(array(':date' => $date, ':tat_name' => $_POST['beschuldigter'], ':opfer_name' => $aaa['Name'], ':vergehen' => $_POST['vergehen'], ':content' => $_POST['content'], ':one-url' => $_POST['one-bild'], ':two-url' => $_POST['two-bild'], ':three-url' => $_POST['three-bild']));
```

Comment: `-` is not a valid character in identifiers. Consider using `_` instead.

Comment: One of your variables that you pass to execute is probably not defined, dump them all with var_dump to see the values

Comment: These `one-url, two-url, three-url` need to be wrapped in backticks `\`` - SQL thinks you want to do math, which is being *silently* interpreted as "one minus url" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table and columns containing hyphens must be wrapped in backticks.

SQL thinks you want to do math, which is being *silently* interpreted as "`one` **minus** `url`" etc.

Therefore, you either change your code to the following:

```
(date, tat_name, opfer_name, vergehen, content, `one-url`, `two-url`, `three-url`)
```

or rename your columns by changing the hyphens to underscores `_`.

```
(date, tat_name, opfer_name, vergehen, content, one_url, two_url, three_url)
```

For more information on identifiers, visit:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html**

Quoting the manual:

```
If any components of a multiple-part name require quoting,  
quote them individually rather than quoting the name as a whole.  
For example, write `my-table`.`my-column`, not `my-table.my-column`.
```

---

See [**Bill Karwin's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3168679/) also.

*Pulled from Bill's answer:*

Yes, you can use punctuation, white space, international characters, and SQL reserved words if you use *delimited identifiers*:

```
SELECT * FROM `my-table`;
```

In MySQL, use the back-ticks.  In standard SQL, use double-quotes.

Or if you use MySQL you can set the [`ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes):

```
SET SQL_MODE = ANSI_QUOTES;
SELECT * FROM "my-table";
```

---

Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you are not already doing so.