# Can not insert data in Mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I can not insert data into mysql because of database error 1048.I have been searching from almost 1 week, but i couldn't find any solution. please help me. Here is all the stuff...

controller users.php:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Users extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        #$this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('users_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['user_list'] = $this->users_model->get_all_users();
        $this->load->view('show_users', $data);
    }

    public function add_form()
    {
        $this->load->view('insert');
    }

    public function insert_new_user()
    {
        $udata['Username'] = $this->input->post('name');
        $udata['Email-Id'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $udata['Address'] = $this->input->post('address');
        $udata['Mobile'] = $this->input->post('mobile');
        $res = $this->users_model->insert_users_to_db($udata);

        if($res)
        {
            header("location: http://localhost/crudcode/index.php/users_model/insert_users_to_db");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Hello";
        }
    }

}
```

Model  users_model.php:

```
<?php

class Users_model extends CI_Model 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_all_users()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function insert_users_to_db($udata)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('users', $udata);
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('id'=>$id));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

}

?>
```

view  insert.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>CI Insert Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="localhost/crudcode/index.php/users/insert_new_user">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="5">

    <tr>
        <th width="213" align="right" scope="row">Enter your username</th>
        <td width="161"><input type="text" name="name" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th align="right" scope="row">Enter your email</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th align="right" scope="row">Enter your Mobile</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="mobile" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th align="right" scope="row">Enter Your Address</th>
        <td><textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th align="right" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o75W7.png)

Comment: I have done this but. It shows only blank page and no data is added to the table but the error 1048 is gone @saty

Comment: Print_r($_POST); CHK WHAT R U getting

Comment: Ok guys, The problem has been solved. I think the actual problem was that i coud not send data from form to controller. That is solved. Thank you so much for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

Have you check if the data from the form is submitted? like

```
public function insert_new_user()
{
    print_r($this->input->post());
}
```

and check the array you've pass on the user model and the last query as well.

```
public function insert_users_to_db($udata)
{
    $this->db->insert('users', $udata);
    print_r($udata);
    echo $this->db->last_query();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can try with changing the FORM action from

```
<form method="post" action="localhost/crudcode/index.php/users/insert_new_user">
```

TO

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/users/insert_new_user" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not submitting an empty form.
The problem could be that there is a redirect happening which is not carrying your $POST data.

Have you tried using this as an action (with the right trailing /):

```
http://localhost/crudcode/index.php/users/insert_new_user/
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `insert_user_to_db()` twice.

First with:

```
$res = $this->users_model->insert_users_to_db($udata);
```

and in this call you're sending the values from the `$udata array.`

And then with:

```
if($res)
{
    header("location: http://localhost/crudcode/index.php/users_model/insert_users_to_db");
}
```

and this call does not include any arguments so it's probably in this call it fails.

What happens if you exclude the second call and just to like this?

```
$res = $this->users_model->insert_users_to_db($udata);
echo print_r($res, true);
```

Genereally speaking you should not need/should not redirect to a model. Those kind of redirects should be handled by the controller(s).

Comment: It shows the same error, nothing happened after changing the code

Comment: what are the values of the array $udata then? Just var_dump($udata) and remove insert-function temporarily.

Comment: Ok, It is showing also null in the value of the array.

Comment: That's the actual issue then. You don't get values given from the form for some reason. If you try echo $this->input->post('name'); and echo $_POST['name']; What does it display?

Answer (score 0):

1)Better to use form_open() and form_close().

2)Check Array which you are inserting.Columns names should match with the assoc array.

Answer (score -1):

I believe `Email-Id` is an invalid field name. If you have named a field that way, you must escape it like:

```
`Email-Id`
```

or more accurately:

```
$udata['`Email-Id`'] = $this->input->post('email');
```

Though a much better solution is to rename the field, because that isn't even a naming convention. Either use only CamelCase or only underscore_names. A dash not a valid character for a field/variable name in any language I know of.

Comment: Why is Email-Id an invalid name?

Comment: because it contains a `-`. That is a symbol with syntactical meaning in SQL and pretty-much every language.

Comment: That is simply not true. It's possible to rename a fieldcolumn like that. In MySQL it is anyway.

Comment: Just because MySQL allows you to do the wrong thing most of the time, it doesn't mean it's the right thing. Did you even try my suggestion before voting it down?

Comment: "Just because MySQL allows you to do the wrong thing most of the time" Based on what?

Comment: MySQL allows you to insert dates like `0000-00-00`, `2015-00-00` and to insert NULLS into `NOT NULL` columns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168644/can-a-table-field-contain-a-hyphen    Please provide with answer(s) based on facts instead of subjective guesses. Btw, dates has absolutely nothing to do with this.