# Whats wrong with my SQLite query?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "-": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE new_info(user-name TEXT,user_mob TEXT,user_email TEXT);

Code:

```
public String CREATE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+ UserContract.addnew.TABLE_NAME+"("+ UserContract.addnew.USER_NAME+" TEXT,"
            + UserContract.addnew.MOBILE+" TEXT,"+ UserContract.addnew.EMAIL+" TEXT);";
```

Comment: `near "-"` there is only one `-` in your query ...

Comment: `user-name` should be `user_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the query it tries to execute: `CREATE TABLE new_info(user-name TEXT,user_mob TEXT,user_email TEXT);` You have `-` instead of `_`. Just replace `user-name` with `user_name`.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168644/can-a-table-field-contain-a-hyphen) to understand how to be able to use hyphen in the table names.

Comment: Or if the table name is `user-name` change your query to ``CREATE TABLE new_info(`user-name` TEXT,user_mob TEXT,user_email TEXT);``

Comment: Yes, basically that's in the other post I linked, did not want to copy the code here :)

Comment: @RanaArslan Mark Vucko's answer as an answer by clicking on the Tick.

Comment: Thanks @Subby :D You can do that if the answer helped you solve and understand, Rana. Have fun coding!