# table names and fields with space and special characters

Tags: java

I have a column name in a database table how do I use it in a java select statement.

```
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select rec-date from pub.std");
```

`-` is always treated as end of column name.

Comment: What DBMS do you use? if mysql then `\`rec-date\`` should do the job

Comment: It's not a "Java" select statement, it's a select statement for whatever database you use.  (This has nothing to do with Java.)  Different databases have different ways of enclosing identifiers.  You'd need to use whatever the way is for your database.  Likely backticks, possibly square brackets, possibly something else.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168644/can-a-table-field-contain-a-hyphen) MySQL: wrap the table or column name in ` and others use "s

Comment: The DBMS is progress.

Comment: If you this select statement in progress client it works perfect, problem comes if you write the same statement to access the database through a java program