# code not displaying result on wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am new to WordPress and I am trying to retrieve data from the database using **wpdb**.

I have created a custom template in order to add the `PHP` code but when I tried to display the retrieved data, it did not show anything.

where is the error ?

**search info.php**

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: search info
*/

get_header();

global $wpdb;  
$result = $wpdb->get_var('select owner-name from owner-info where owner-id= 5');
echo $result;

get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: You are looking for blog author name? Clarify your requirement.

Comment: no its a custom table that i created and contain these required fields

Comment: [You should use delimited identifier like backticks for mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168644/can-a-table-field-contain-a-hyphen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress, there is a table prefix (default : 'wp_' or which you have provided) in each table name, please check & include in the table name if required, then your table name will be 'wp_owner-info' & if 'wp_' is not added in your table name then keep as it is.

And the code will be:

With prefix i.e. table_name = wp_owner-info

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: search info
*/

get_header();

global $wpdb;  
$result = $wpdb->get_results("select owner-name from wp_owner-info where owner-id= 5");
echo $result;

get_footer();
?>
```

OR

Now without prefix i.e. table_name = 'owner-info'

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: search info
*/

get_header();

global $wpdb;  
$result = $wpdb->get_results("select owner-name from owner-info where owner-id= 5");
echo $result;

get_footer();
?>
```

I hope, this will be useful for you.

Comment: table name is owner-info you are saying that i need to rename the table name to wp_owner-info ?? or what ?

Comment: If you are saying that your table_name is owner-info, then use the code of without table prefix. Find my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom query with global varibale $wpdb where you can use dynamic database prefix of table name in query as standred method

```
$tablename = $wpdb->owner-name;
$ownerID = 5;
$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE owner-id=%s",$ownerID );
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

Comment: i tried your answer it display the word "array" still not working

Comment: yes, then try var_dump($result); or print_r($result); and check what do you get.

Comment: make sure about your table name from which your trying to fetch data.

Comment: table name is owner-info it is right but still the same result after using var_dump and print_r

Comment: remove $wpdb-> and use $tablename  = 'owner-name'; in above code.

Answer (score 0):

If its showing blank or white page. then you need to enable wordpress debug mode to know what's wrong with your code. 
**Enable WP Debug**

1. Open wp_config.php file under WordPress root directory.
2. Find define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ); and set it to true. 
   example define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Refresh your WordPress page. here you got the error message. Post your error message here. We will give you the fix. you can fix it by yourself :)

Comment: thanks for the advice i didn't know about it ... bust still the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your table structure, but dash `-` is not a valid character in table or column names. Replace it with the appropriate char, most likely an underscore `_`, so it becomes

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var('select owner_name from owner_info where owner_id= 5');
```

---

If the name really includes `-`, you must quote identifiers with backticks, see [MySQL - Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) for details

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var('select `owner-name` from `owner-info` where `owner-id`= 5');
```