# MySQL Join vs. dot in table name

Tags: php, mysql

During the reproduction of the old client script, I encountered a problem.
They have two tables in a database called "content.articles" and "content.categories"

```
    SELECT content.articles.*, content.categories.id as category_id
    FROM `content.articles`
    INNER JOIN `content.categories`
    ON content.articles.category=content.articles.id
```

I understand that the problem is the dots in the table name.
How should I select properly?

I tried:

```
    SELECT content.articles.*
    SELECT `content.articles`.*
    SELECT `content.articles.*`
```

None of these options work.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: \`content\`.\`articles\`.*

Comment: The table itself is called 'content.articles'? Or 'articles' is a table in 'content'?

Comment: they are two tables with dots "content.articles" and "content.categories"

Comment: I guess `content` is db name and `articles` is a table name and its normal you can query a table like `dbname.tablename`

Comment: If, as you say, the dots are in the table name then your second option should work.

Comment: no no. Table name is "sh214918_shop", and there are tables with dots

Comment: Then you have not provided all of the information necessary to solve your problem. You say the table name is 'sh214918_shop' and the you say the table names have dots. Which one is it?

Comment: Are you connected to the *database* `sh214918_shop`? You need to show us your ***actual*** code in order for us to help us resolve the issue. *Help us, help you.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table references in the `FROM` clause are correct, then the second form you tried should be valid... enclose the whole identifier in backticks. e.g.

```
SELECT `content.articles`.*
  FROM `content.articles`
```

The backticks allow for a lot of wonky characters which would otherwise be interpretted as part SQL text and throw errors.

```
SELECT `ab.d@ AND '0'`.*
  FROM `ab.d@ AND '0'`
       ^             ^
```

---

I'm a little suspicious of the table references in the FROM clause. The dot separator is used between the database name and the table name. If the table is named `articles` and is in the `content` database, the identifiers shouldn't be combined inside backticks.  And in that case, we omit the database qualifier from the column name in the SELECT list.

If `articles` is a table in the `content` database, then we'd do like this

```
SELECT `articles`.*
  FROM `content`.`articles`
       ^       ^ ^        ^
```

A convenient pattern is to assign an alias to the table, and use that to qualify column references. Here is an example assigning alias `ca` to the table reference, and using `ca.` to qualify the column references in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT ca.*
  FROM `content`.`articles` ca
       ^       ^ ^        ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Having dots or other punctuation or even whitespace in table names is permitted by SQL, but you have to "delimit" the identifiers whenever you use them in a query.

It's unusual and not recommended to use a dot in the table name, because it's easy to confuse that with the `databasename.tablename` [syntax for qualified tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

It would be like if you had a variable in C++ called `Foo::Bar`. People reading the code would be like: Wait, is that Bar in the *class* Foo? Or is it a variable that is literally called Foo::Bar? Why in the world would you do such a thing!?!

You can resolve strange table names like this by using identifier delimiters. And you *must* use the delimiters every time you reference that sort of table name.

Comment: +10  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168644/can-a-table-field-contain-a-hyphen